# How to fix Nicotine+ connection status: INVALIDPASS

Tags: connection

How to fix Nicotine+ connection status: INVALIDPASS

I have Ubuntu 16.04 64bit.
If I do the Nicotine Fast Configure the port is closed.

Thanks in advanced for your time and effort.

Adam

Comment: Is there any logs or error messages that you can post to help resolve this?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reaction. I'm a total newbe so I don know how to see the logs and the error message is:   Can not login, reason: INVALIDPASS.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the username worked for me.

Go to: Edit → Settings → General → Server.

(I guess the reason is typing already existing username.)